# Try to uploading ipa "Invalid bundle.."

Tags: ios, javafx, ipa, gluon

I try to upload my IPA by Application Loader, but I've got this error since i changed the version number CFBundleVersion

ERROR ITMS-90503: "Invalid Bundle. Apps that have 'arm64' in the list of UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in Info.plist must only contain the arm64 slice."

But in my plist is all correct, also this key:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>arm64</string>
    </array>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to check the valid architectures in the build settings. Be sure to have selected "All" in the right top-right corner and verify that there is only arm64 in the valid architectures.

Comment: The configuration which you used to build archive had Build Active Architecture Only set to Yes.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `createIpa` task builds for `armv7` and `arm64`. If you want to build only the latter modify your build.gradle file:

```
jfxmobile {
    ...
    ios {
        arch = "arm64"
        ipaArchs = ["arm64"]
        ...
    }
}
```

In case it is needed you can also specify the architecture and the minimum iOS version in your pList file:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
            <string>arm64</string>
    </array> 
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
<string>9.0</string>
```